# spree.i18n don't change the default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, spree

I'm trying to translate to :pt-BR which translation is all complete by http://www.localeapp.com/projects/4605 but I'm having the same error on the screenshot. Changes in application.rb `config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'` and put the pt-BR.yml file on config/locales. Also tryed to change the file name like suggested to spree_i18n.pt-BR.yml but also don't works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement localization in Spree is to include the [spree_i18n](https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n) gem.  Follow the instructions listed there, and set your locale in config/application.rb as you have done.  You shouldn't need to copy any of the locale files to your local repository.